# How to give javascript unique ID in htmleditfor method in .net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to give a unique id to htmleditfor method. I want to add Jquery datepicker in it. Please guide...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdExpiryDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" } })
```

Comment: It already has a unique `id` attribute - its `id="AdExpiryDate"` (look at the html you generate)

Answer (score 0):

Your generated html will look like this

```
<input type="text" id="AdExpiryDate" value="AdExpiryDate" />
```

You just need to add following javascript code at bottom of your view

```
<script>
  $('#AdExpiryDate').datepicker();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, MVC will automatically add the property name from your model to the id and name attributes on the HTML element. However if you want to specify your own id for the element, just update your htmlAttributes:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdExpiryDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY", id = "ad-expiry-date" } })
```

Then just update your javascript to target the new id that you added:

```
<script>
  var expireDate = $('#ad-expiry-date').val();
  alert(expireDate);
</script>
```